# submit button not inside form element

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am working on a form design, which doesn't have submit button inside `<form>` tags. This is what I mean:

http://codepen.io/timsim/pen/aJjdGa

The design I am working on requires to input data, that I will submit, to be across the website and not within the same element block. Can this be done? What is the best practice approach to handle this kind of problem?

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail">
  </div>

</form>
<div id="other">
Some other element here
</div>
<div>
SUBMIT BUTTOM HERE
</div>
```

Comment: Use a javascript element to cause a form submission upon button press, but really, what is your exact reason not to wrap it in a `<form>` element?

Comment: `The design I am working on requires to input data, that I will submit, to be across the website and not within the same element block` *Why*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using jQuery. Make sure you include this in your page and then you can do something like this ..

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="the-form">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail">
  </div>

</form>
<div id="other">
Some other element here
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#" id="submit-the-form">Submit the form</a>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('#submit-the-form').click(function() {
        $('#the-form').submit();
    });

});

</script>
```

So there is an ID on the `<form>` tag and an ID on the text link I've added. The text link, when clicked, will trigger jQuery to submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery you can add an `id` to your form and submit it manually like this :

```
    $('.js-submit-form').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // not necessary if you're using a div
      $('#myform').submit()
    });

    <form action="#" method="post" id="myform">
    ...
    </form> 

    <div class="js-submit-form">SUBMIT BUTTOM HERE</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add an event handler to the button, and in that handler, submit the form.

```css
body {
  background-color:aqua;
}
form{
  width:30%;
  display:inline-block;
}
#other{
  height:200px;
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" id="form">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail">
  </div>
</form>
<div id="other">
Some other element here
</div>
<div>
  <input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit()">
</div>
```

And if you want to use more than 1 button, just give the buttons a class or something, and write an external event handler for it that submits your form. No need for jQuery, it's pretty simple vanilla javascript.

```js
var submits = document.getElementsByClassName('submit');

for (var i = 0; i < submits.length; i++) {
  submits[i].addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('form').submit();
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color:aqua;
}
form{
  width:30%;
  display:inline-block;
}
#other{
  height:200px;
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" id="form">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail">
  </div>
</form>
<div id="other">
Some other element here
</div>
<div>
  <input class="submit" type="submit">
  <input class="submit" type="submit">
  <input class="submit" type="submit">
</div>
```